# Columns with same colors using barplot() in R

Tags: r, colors, plot

I have some problems with colors in my barplot. I have a 4x4 matrix "allmat":

```
          A             B           C         D
L   0.10260     0.0215700   3.017e-01   0.06917

F   0.09840     0.0206900   2.009e-01   0.11450

M   0.14100     0.0065630   3.252e-01   0.35050

G   0.02121     0.0006811   5.454e-06   0.13810
```

To plot the columns in one graph I use:

```
mp<-barplot(allmat,beside=T,axisnames=F,col=c("red","black","green","blue"))
mtext(1,at=mp,text=c("L","F","M","G"),line=0,cex=0.5)
mtext(1,at=colMeans(mp),text=c("A","B","C","D"),line=2)
```

What I get is that every row has the same color, but I want the columns be of the same color. How do I do that?

Best,

Eugen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually assign a color to each bar individually.

```
mp<-barplot(allmat,beside=T,axisnames=F,
            col=c(rep("red",4),rep("black",4),rep("green",4),rep("blue",4)))
```

Comment: As usually, I completely forgot about "rep". Thank you very much.

Comment: `col` could also be `col = rep(c('red', 'black', 'green', 'blue'), each=4)` this avoid writing `rep('Color.Name', 4)` each time.